# How do I use AND and OR in a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, operator-precedence

This is my SQL and data is feed by PHP

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 
WHERE approve='true' AND `description`like '%".$name."%' OR  `name`like '%".$name."%' OR `location` like '%".$location."%'
```

I am able to view records where `approve` is `false` when I process this query.

Comment: What error(s) do you receive? You are likely open to SQL injections with this code. Maybe you need to use groupings `()` because `and` will conflict with `or` statements.

Comment: OR how do i use AND and OR in a single statement

Comment: that sql  should rows that approve='true'  and now search description and the other columns

Comment: It currently runs as `approve='true' AND `description`like '%".$name."%'` then `or` and `name like '%".$name."%'` and `or` and `location like '%".$location."%'`. Group the `or` bits together so those are the optional bits, as the answer below states.

Comment: I've updated the question as I think it should have been written, please adjust if that is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `OR`ed conditions should go into parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    approve = 'true' 
    AND (
        `description` like CONCAT('%', :name, '%') 
        OR  `name`    like CONCAT('%', :name, '%') 
        OR `location` like CONCAT('%', :location, '%') 
    )
```

Comment: (I'd swap the placeholders to `?` in case `mysqli` is being used)